# How to efficiently grow a vector in R?

Tags: r, arrays, performance

Let's say you have a function that takes a number as an input and outputs a vector. However, the output vector size depends on the input and you can't calculate it before the function.

For example, take the [3N+1 famous algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture). A simple implementation of that algorithm, returning the whole path until 1 could look like this:

```
compute <- function(x) {
  if (x %% 2 == 0)
    return(x / 2)
  return(3*x + 1)
}

algo <- function(x) {
  if (x == 1)
    return(1)

  output <- x
  while(x != 1) {
    x <- compute(x)
    output <- c(output, x)
  }

  return(output)
}
```

The `algo` function returns the whole path of an input X to 1, according to the function. As you can tell, the `output` variable grows dynamically, using the `c()` (combine) function.

Are there any alternatives to this? Is growing a list faster? Should I adopt some classic dynamic vector logic, such as initializing an empty N-sized vector and double it everytime it goes full?

**EDIT**: Please don't mind trying to optimize the way my helper functions are structured. I get it, but that's not the point here! I am only concerned about the `c()` function and an alternative to it.

Comment: Pivoting to how much memory to allocate, for initial values up to 1,000,000, the maximum length of the output vector is 525 using `n <- sapply(1:1e6, function(x) length(algo(x)))`.

Comment: Please note that this was just an example, I am not particularly interested in solving this problem. It was just a small story!

Comment: Have a look at https://privefl.github.io/blog/why-loops-are-slow-in-r/.

Comment: @F.Privé Interesting article, but I would add extra warning that JIT compilation in R is not what is usually meant by JIT. I.e., it's not compiled to native code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update

As per your edit, maybe you can check the following solution

```
algo_TIC2 <- function(x) {
  res <- x
  repeat {
    u <- tail(res, 1)
    if (u != 1) {
      res[length(res) + 1] <- if (u %% 2) 3 * u + 1 else u / 2
    } else {
      return(res)
    }
  }
}
```

---

You can use recursions like below

```
compute <- function(x) if (x %% 2) 3*x + 1 else x / 2
algo_TIC1 <- function(x) {
  if (x == 1) {
    return(1)
  }
  c(x, algo_TIC1(compute(x)))
}
```

and you will see

```
> algo_TIC1(3000)
 [1] 3000 1500  750  375 1126  563 1690  845 2536 1268  634  317  952  476  238
[16]  119  358  179  538  269  808  404  202  101  304  152   76   38   19   58
[31]   29   88   44   22   11   34   17   52   26   13   40   20   10    5   16
[46]    8    4    2    1
```

---

If you don't want any helper function, i.e., `compute`, you can try

```
algo_TIC1 <- function(x) {
  if (x == 1) {
    return(1)
  }
  c(x, algo_TIC1(if (x %% 2) 3*x + 1 else x / 2))
}
```

Comment: That is elegant, but does it address his _efficiency concern_ for vector size?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel It seems not :(

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use `ifelse()` here.  Just use `if (x %% 2) 3*x + 1 else x / 2`.  It's about 4 times faster for that part of the calculation.

Comment: @user2554330 Thanks a lot for your suggestion. It's indeed faster!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't believe this addresses my problem. In fact, it looks pretty much the same with respect to dynamically growing the vector.

Answer (score 1):

So, what bothers you is reallocation, and you are right. Let's see.

```
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark({
  a <- c()
  for (i in seq(1e4)) {
    a <- c(a, i)
  }
})

microbenchmark({
  a <- numeric(1e4)
  for (i in seq(1e4)) {
    a[[i]] <- i
  }
})

microbenchmark({
  a <- numeric(1)
  k <- 1
  for (i in seq(1e4)) {
    if (i > k) {
      a <- c(a, numeric(k))
      k <- k + k
    }
    a[[i]] <- i
  }
  a <- head(a, 1e4)
})
```

And the timings:

```
Append
     min       lq      mean   median       uq      max neval
 78.0162 78.67925  83.36224 79.54515 81.79535 166.6988   100

Preallocate
     min       lq     mean    median       uq      max neval
1.484901 1.516051 1.567897    1.5552 1.569451 1.895601   100

Amortize
     min       lq     mean    median       uq      max neval
3.316501 3.377201  3.62415  3.484351 3.585701  11.7596   100
```

Never append many elements to a vector. If possible, preallocate, otherwise amortized allocation will do.

Even if you don't know the actual size beforehand, you may have an upper bound. Then you can still preallocate and truncate in the end. Even a reasonable estimate is useful: preallocate that size, and then resort to amortization if needed.

---

A remark: R is not good at loops. For small loops, for instance over variables of a dataframe or files in a directory, there is usually no problem. But if you have a long computation that really needs to be achieved with many loops and you can't vectorize, R might not be the right tool. On occasions, writing a function in C, C++, Fortran or Java could help: it's fairly easy to build plugins or to use Rcpp, and the performance gain is considerable.

Comment: Thank you! But that does not quite answer it. The examples you provided have the size known before the computation. What if you don't know that you need 1e4 elements?

Comment: Setting the length is a tiny bit faster than appending an empty vector.  I.e. replace `a <- c(a, numeric(k)); k <- k+k` with `k <- k + k; length(a) <- k` for a small speedup.

Comment: @eduardokapp In the last example, you don't need to know beforehand, it was just needed for the benchmark. You may use a while loop, and keep track of the actual number of items written, and truncate to that size in the end, the mechanism to grow the vector is the same.

Comment: @user2554330 I didn't know this trick, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the length of a vector and then make assignments to specific elements.  Your code would look like this:

```
algo2 <- function(x) {
  if (x == 1)
    return(1)

  output <- x
  index <- 1
  while(x != 1) {
    x <- compute(x)
    index <- index + 1
    if (index > length(output))
      length(output) <- 2*length(output)
    output[index] <- x
  }

  return(output[seq_len(index)])
}
```

This makes a difference, though not a big one in your example, because all those calls to `compute()` (and `return()`!) are quite costly.  If you folded that calculation into `algo` you'd see more improvement.  You could also initialize `output` to a length that is likely to be good enough for most cases, and rarely need doubling.

Comment: Right, my example was merely for a narrative, easier to understand purposes. So your idea is using the traditional "double the array when you need a bigger array" strategy, right?

Comment: Yes, that may be the best way to increase, though I imagine it depends on the problem.  But the main points are to limit the number of increases, use `length( ) <-` to set them, and assign to specific locations.